# Struggle with gated sound - Fuzz stompbox

Tags: transistors, guitar-pedal

I built my first fuzz pedal based on the Tone Reaper but I can't handle with gated sound.

[image: Schematic pcbguitarmania]

Whatever the fuzz pot is set the sound is gated. At low position the signal is very weak and chopped, even with no compressor in the signal chain.

I verified all components and replaced the 2N2369 but nothing improved.

I guess there is a Bias problem. On Q9 the voltage on base is 0.2V, Emitter 0V and collector 8.36V so the base is not so high to work properly.

In another similar built one AC176 is used and rest of the board is still the same. I don't know why.

Comment: Gwen Grand - Hi, When a post copies or adapts material (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) from elsewhere, that content must be [correctly referenced](/help/referencing). For online content, the source webpage / PDF / video etc. should be named & linked as a minimum (see the rule about references for offline books / articles). Therefore please [edit] your question to add the appropriate source reference (e.g. source name & link) for that image, and remember to include references in future. (As you are new here, please see the [tour] & [help] as rules here differ from typical forums). TY

Comment: 1. "*... based on the Tone Reaper ...*" Um, what is "the Tone Reaper"? 2. "... but I can't handle with gated sound.*" What does that mean?

"

Comment: Tone reaper is the name of the board. Gated sound means that you need to hit guitar strings heavy to make the signal out of the transistor

Comment: What's with the shaded areas on the schematic?

Comment: @Hearth May have been a gray background that someone tried to fill with white and it missed those areas.

Comment: Now I see what the gray is, it's a watermark with the name of the website the schematic came from that has been partially removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An AC176 is a germanium transistor, while the 2N2369 is silicon. The base-emitter voltage of germanium transistors is around 0.3 V, silicon 0.6 V. Germaniums also have more leakage currents. Substituting one for the other is going to require different biasing. Even if you increase the bias on Q9 it’s not going to sound the same. This is why pedal builders seek out and pay top dollar for germanium transistors.

**Update:** According to the parts list in the documentation found [here](https://pcbguitarmania.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Reaper-Device-Building-Docs-1.pdf) the second transistor should be an AC176. The schematic shows a 2N2369, I don't know if that's a mistake or intentional as a weak attempt to thwart copying. The schematic in the link also shows the transistors as Q1 and Q2, unlike the one in the question where they are Q8 and Q9, so it may be an early version that has been updated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case with 0.2v what best solution I have with this genuine circuit? Try a germanium?

Comment: @GwenGrand Other than getting a germanium transistor, which is probably the best option, you could try adding some bias to Q9. As is, it’s pretty much running Class C, the transistor is off for small signals, it’s only when you play hard that it gets enough voltage on its base to turn on. Try something like 1 meg from the base to +9V.

Comment: Replacing Q9 by an Ac176 is the best replacement?

Comment: @GwenGrand Yes, that's the one specified in the PDF the schematic originally came from. It shows one part number in the schematic, a different one in the parts list.

Comment: Problem solved, I replaced by AC176 and it sounds....awesome!

Comment: @GwenGrand Great, thanks for letting us know it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The first stage is a high gain amplifier.  I haven't worked through the bias calculations to see if the output would have symmetrical clipping.  Because the emitter resistor is bypassed, the stage gain is high - probably high enough to have clipping distortion even with a low input signal.  The clipping produces the fuzz effect.  Note that the first stage has a bit of intentional high-frequency roll-off, cause by feedback capacitor C21.

In this circuit it looks like the fuzz effect is produced by a combination of two diodes in inverse parallel, and over-driven amplifier stages.  The two inverse diodes are D7 and the Q9 base-emitter junction.  Changing Q9 from Ge to Si will have a very noticeable effect on the sound.

The Fuzz control drives another gain stage, and this one definitely clips the signal.  This one is biased by "catching" the negative peaks of the signal with D7.  Working with C24, this holds the signal negative peaks at -0.7 V.  Depending on the transistor type, Q9 will begin to amplify when the peak-to-peak signal amplitude out of the Fuzz pot is either 0.9 V or 1.3 V.

Thinking through the circuit, this part of it is a bit strange, and the previous description is not entirely correct.  Because there is no DC path go GND from the right side of C23, exactly when Q9 goes from completely off - to a linear amplifier - to a clipping amplifier is not clearly defined for low-amplitude signals.  I think this is the "gating" you are experiencing, but please update your question with a more detailed description of what you want and what you are getting.

Also -

Without C22, the Q8 stage tries to have a gain of over 300, which the transistor can barely do.  With C22 in there, it tries for infinite gain above 480 Hz.  I'm not a fuzz box guru, but this seems like a lot for a guitar preamp stage.

Is it your intent to have a circuit that produces a clean output signal at low Fuzz setting, with increasing fuzz as the pot is rotated?  If so, some very minor tweaks to the circuit can do that.

Comment: Great analysis! The gated effect is the fact you need to hit the guitar stings strong to make the pedal working properly. Normally with fuzz pot (or gain) at minimum you hear your clean signal dry or slightly colored by the circuitry. That's my intention

Comment: Maybe adding a resistor from DC to Q9 base is good solution. What do you think? What resistance would be suitable?